# Angular: Instantiate class having StaticProvider as a parameter

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-providers

I am trying to instantiate a class having a StaticProvider. Below is the code

**main.ts**

```
 export function providerFactory() {
  //some code
   return result; //result is string
 }

 const providers = [
   { provide: 'TEST', useFactory: providerFactory, deps: [] }
 ];

 function BootstrapModule() {
    platformBrowserDynamic(providers)
    .bootstrapModule(module)
    .catch(error);
 }
```

**demo.ts**

```
 export class Demo  {
  constructor(@Inject('TEST') private test: string) {
 }
```

Now I want to call the `demo` by the following code:

```
 let t = new Demo() // error occurs
```

I tried a lot but not able to find the solution.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using Angular's DI and creating these instances on the fly just pass the `providerFactory` as a constructor argument.

`let t = new Demo(providerFactor())`.

Then remove the Injection annotation from your Demo class